CryptoJs - Encrypt/Decrypt by PHP and Javascript
Demo structure:
        data = {
            test: $("#testCode").val(),

        }

    data1 = encryptData(data, 'test');
    console.log(data1);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            data1

        },
    });

    // Encrypt data using CryptoJS AES encryption
    function encryptData(data, key) {
        const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), key).toString();
        return encryptedData;
    }


    <?php
    // Get the encrypted data from the AJAX request
    $encryptedData = $_POST['encryptedData'];

    $encryptionKey = "test";

    // Decrypt the data using PHP OpenSSL decryption
    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedData), 'aes-256-cbc', $encryptionKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

    echo json_encode(['decryptedData' => $decryptedData]);
    ?>

I want to decrypt my AJAX request and encrypt that ajax request in PHP. Basically, I want the payload of my AJAX request to be encrypted. However, I need to display the decrypted data later on that page.
So the above code is not working.

You forgot to ask a question about this

Why do you even need this? Using https in your site will encrypt the data during the ajax request anyway

I want the payload of my AJAX request to be encrypted...again, HTTPS already does this for you automatically. You've edited the question but it doesn't clarify why you need this, or what "not working" actually means in this context - is there an error? Unexpected result? Some logic issue? Although this process is probably pointless (because of HTTPS), if you did want help with it you should clarify what you are actually seeing when you run the code. See also [ask]. Thanks.
